# How to use sync.pool for slices correctly

Tags: go

I am building a Go app to serve thousands of HTTP requests. The serving includes parsing the input, processing it and returning the output.

The input parsing includes parsing `json` to a list of `map[string]string`

How can I implement memory pooling for this parsing?

**Minimum Reproducible Example:**

```
var poolTest *sync.Pool

func init() {
    poolTest = &sync.Pool{
        New: func() interface{} {
            return new([]map[string]string)
        },
    }
}

func Requesthandler (ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    poolTestList  := poolTest.Get().(*[]map[string]string)
    input := ctx.PostBody()
    _=json.Unmarshal(input, poolTestList)

    //do something
    print(*(poolTestList))
   
     //clear and return to pool
    (*poolTestList) = (*poolTestList)[:0]
    poolTest.Put(poolTestList)
}

func main() {
    _ = (&fasthttp.Server{
        Handler:        Requesthandler,
        ReadBufferSize: 8192,
        TCPKeepalive: true,
    }).ListenAndServe(":3000")
}
```

The part I am confused about is clearing and returning to pool.

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: You're passing a `**[]map[string]string` to `Unmarshal`, which is probably not what you intend. The slice allocation is probably not the bottleneck here -- you've allocated many to even get this far into an http request, and all the data is going to be in the maps, with newly allocated structures. Are you sure `sync.Pool` is offering you any benefit at all?

Comment: This is fundamentely wrong. Start of with correct code. If GC pressure is the actual bottleneck then  optimize. Reusing the slice without the maps is pretty pointless and reusing map memmory is hard. If GC pressure is your problem: implement your own json.Unmarshaler

Comment: You do realize that "thousands of requests" is nothing for any modern computer, right?  (Unless you mean per second) This looks very much like premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is generally correct, but there are a couple of odd things here. First, you almost never need a pointer to a slice; you definitely don't seem to need one here. Your values should just be `[]map[string]string` not `*[]map[string]string`.

Second, [per the examples](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_Pool), the best practice is to reset the pooled object after `Get`, not before `Put`. This is safest because it means `Get` is not making any potentially unsafe assumptions about the values it receives from the pool. You could also do both if items tend to stay in the pool for a long time and are quite large (there's a potential here for very high memory usage from slices of maps, so this will depend on your use case).

Just to note, what's in `//do something` could be relevant, because you're working with maps and slices here which behave with reference semantics. If any slice or map leaks this method, you could run into some potential issues with inadvertently shared memory which might be very difficult to diagnose.

Lastly, remember that this code is *not* pooling the maps, *only* the slices. So the benefit here may be very little if these are short lists of large maps. In fact, it may be very little even if they are long lists of maps. I would remove the pooling code, benchmark & profile, and make sure that you're actually optimizing something relevant to performance.